# How to change the font size, color, and style while setting `engine = htmlwidget` as a parameter of plot function?

Tags: r, fonts, igraph, htmlwidgets, arules

**Background of the Problem**

I was trying the plot the rules, found after applying [mineCARs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arulesCBA/versions/1.2.0/topics/mineCARs) of R.

```
plot(top10subRules, method = "graph", engine='htmlwidget')
```

However, the default font, and it's color does not become completely visible when I set the plot as an image in the MS word file. Thus, I wanted to increase the font size. Also, I wanted to change the font color and style (to Times New Roman) of the plotted rules. I know that in R, I have to change the value of `cex` to change the font size in graph. However, when I set `engine='htmlwidget'` and `cex=some_value` as parameters of the `plot()` function, I get the following error.

> Warning message: "Unknown control parameters: cex"
>
> Available control parameters (with default values):
>
> itemCol    =
> #CBD2FC nodeCol    =  c("#EE0000", "#EE0303", "#EE0606", "#EE0909", "#EE0C0C", "#EE0F0F", "#EE1212", "#EE1515", "#EE1818", "#EE1B1B",
> "#EE1E1E", "#EE2222", "#EE2525", "#EE2828", "#EE2B2B", "#EE2E2E",
> "#EE3131", "#EE3434", "#EE3737", "#EE3A3A", "#EE3D3D", "#EE4040",
> "#EE4444", "#EE4747", "#EE4A4A", "#EE4D4D", "#EE5050", "#EE5353",
> "#EE5656", "#EE5959", "#EE5C5C", "#EE5F5F", "#EE6262", "#EE6666",
> "#EE6969", "#EE6C6C", "#EE6F6F", "#EE7272", "#EE7575", "#EE7878",
> "#EE7B7B", "#EE7E7E", "#EE8181", "#EE8484", "#EE8888", "#EE8B8B",
> "#EE8E8E", "#EE9191", "#EE9494", "#EE9797", "#EE9999", "#EE9B9B",
> "#EE9D9D", "#EE9F9F", "#EEA0A0", "#EEA2A2", "#EEA4A4", "#EEA5A5",
> "#EEA7A7", "#EEA9A9", "#EEABAB", "#EEACAC", "#EEAEAE", "#EEB0B0",
> "#EEB1B1", "#EEB3B3", "#EEB5B5", "#EEB7B7", "#EEB8B8", "#EEBABA",
> "#EEBCBC", "#EEBDBD", "#EEBFBF", "#EEC1C1", "#EEC3C3", "#EEC4C4",
> "#EEC6C6", "#EEC8C8", "#EEC9C9", "#EECBCB", "#EECDCD", "#EECFCF",
> "#EED0D0", "#EED2D2", "#EED4D4", "#EED5D5", "#EED7D7", "#EED9D9",
> "#EEDBDB", "#EEDCDC", "#EEDEDE", "#EEE0E0",  "#EEE1E1", "#EEE3E3",
> "#EEE5E5", "#EEE7E7", "#EEE8E8", "#EEEAEA", "#EEECEC", "#EEEEEE")
>
> precision  =  3
>
> igraphLayout   =  layout_nicely
>
> interactive    =  TRUE
>
> engine     =  visNetwork
>
> max    =  100
>
> selection_menu     =  TRUE
>
> degree_highlight   =  1
>
> verbose    =  FALSE

**Then, How Did I Try to Solve the Problem?**

As I am new to R, I have tried by reading the official documents. For example, I have read [doc file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesViz/arulesViz.pdf) of `arulesViz` to understand the `engine` parameter. Moreover, I went through the [showcases](https://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_leaflet.html) of htmlwidgets. Apart from these, I searched a lot in google and went through the questions (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63503366/how-to-change-the-font-used-in-htmlwidgets-for-r)) of Stack Overflow where the users asked questions regarding `htmlwidgets`. However, none of the approaches helped me. I also tried by changing the value of `engine`. For example, by setting `engine = igraph` and `engine = interactive`. However, I could not like the plots, appeared after setting those two `engine`s.

**Then, My Question**

How to change the font size, color, and style while setting `engine = htmlwidget` as a parameter of  `plot` function of R?

Thanks for reading the question! Any type of help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

---

***Update for Reproducible Example***

```
library('arulesCBA')
library('arulesViz')

df <- data.frame(Variable_1 = c("High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High"),
                 Variable_2 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"),
                 Variable_3 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No"))

for(i in 1:ncol(df))  df[[i]] <- as.factor(df[[i]])
trans <- as(df, "transactions")
rules <- mineCARs(Variable_3 ~ ., trans,  balanceSupport = TRUE, parameter = list(confidence = 0.6, support=0.1))
plot(rules, method = "graph", engine='htmlwidget', cex=1.5)
```

Comment: @user20650, thanks a lot for your response. I have provided reproducible example in the question's body. Please, check.

Comment: @user20650 Do I need to provide anything else? Please, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've never used `vizNetwork` but from a quick look; 
I thought just using `plt %>% visNodes(font=list(size=25))` might work but no joy. It seems you also have to turn off the `scaling` (whatever that does). So try `plot(rules, method = "graph", engine='htmlwidget') %>%   visNodes(font=list(size=25), scaling=list(label=list(enabled=FALSE)))`

Comment: Hi @user20650,  when you commented, I was sleeping (now it is 1:36 AM). However, after seeing your comment, I woke up and opened my laptop. Due to being slow speed of my laptop, I am somewhat late to start working. Thanks, it worked!!! Can you please post your comment as an answer? It can be helpful for the other users of SO.

Comment: In your answer, if possible, please explain the reasons behind the need to turn off the scaling. Also, you know that `face` parameter can be used to change the font style  (e.g. `font=list(size=50, color='#000000', face = "Times New Roman")` ). If possible, please mention that also. Thanks a lot, again! You are really super helpful.

Comment: after a read of the `scaling` argument in `?visNodes`I think a better option is to, for example, set `label=list(min=20)` or similar. This will then allow the size of the nodes to be scaled. When I switched of the scaling with `enabled=FALSE` this meant the nodes were the same size. So something like `visNodes(font=list(color="white", face="Times New Roman"), scaling=list(label=list(min=30)))` might be enough. You should have a play about with the other arguments of `scaling` to see what they do / if any of them offer a better option.

Comment: @user20650, posting your great response as an answer can help others a lot. Will you please post it? Then, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `plot` method calls `visNetwork` and so I thought this would be enough to change the font size

```
your_plot %>% visNodes(font=list(size=25))
```

But no joy. It seems this is to do with the `scaling=list(label=list(enabled=TRUE))` in the default plot method. You can set this to `FALSE` and then the font size can be increased using the code above but it turns of the scaling of the node sizes.

`?visNodes` gives a bit of info on the `scaling` argument. If you set the `min` value in `scaling` it still allows for the node sizes to be scaled by some size parameter but sets a minimum starting size --> therefore this can be used to increase the font size.

```
plot(rules, method = "graph", engine='htmlwidget') %>%  
  visNodes(font=list(color="white", face="Times New Roman"), 
           scaling=list(label=list(min=30)))
```